# Hard coding my Selenium scripts in Java

Tags: java, selenium, frameworks, webdriver, testng

Hi I am very new in Selenium `WebDriver` and I am at a cross roads right now. I took one module of the application I am working on and wrote the scripts for it. I ended up with a lot of java classes. Now,

- How do I incorporate that into the framework?
- Am I doing the right thing?
- Is it advisable to hard code everything before incorporating it into the framework?

Please help, your input will make a huge difference. Thank you!!!

Comment: Always fail fast and fail smartly, means do not wait until whole thing gets completed to integrate. It should be in pieces, develop and integrate, develop and integrate and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You have done correct thing since you are new to selenium. The next step is to create a very basic framework that can support keyword or data driven approach. You can also go for page object model or page pattern using factory. Again you have to evaluate those frameworks with respect to your project complexity and pick the correct one and develop. 
Hard coding things are not good, you need to try to get rid of hard coding ASAP otherwise tests will not be manageable as test suits grows.

A good test automation framework should have minimum following capability:

1. Scope of code re-usability using helper classes
2. Capable of logging information
3. Modular
4. Data driven.
5. If you want, keyword driven
6. Well formatted object repository.
7. Choose a good unit testing framework and use it.

Hope this information will help you.